# { [Error: , Remote I/O error] errno: 121, code: '', syscall: 'writeByte' } from raspberry pi to Azure

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-stretch, i2c

I tried to follow the instruction below to send sensor data from my raspberry pi 2 to Azure.

[Connect Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub (Node.js)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-node-get-started)

I connected the sensors to my pi device in a different way. Not sure if this is the issue, but I am able to read sensor data through a python script from my raspberry pi terminal. Then when I tried to

```
sudo node index.js '<YOUR AZURE IOT HUB DEVICE CONNECTION STRING>'
```

But received the below error message

```
{ [Error: , Remote I/O error] errno: 121, code: '', syscall: 'writeByte' }
```

I have enabled I2C through Raspberry config. And when I checked i2c addresses, as suggested from my search online, it returned nothing. No number value is returned. What does this mean? Is this the problem that caused the error?

Comment: The `Remote I/O Error` indicates to me that you're able to connect to azure, but are erroring out when you're trying to write the data to azure cloud. Are you able to check and verify that the sensor data is correctly being read on the pi ? I'd start there... i.e check what's being sent to Azure and whether the correct data is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Raspberry Pi has only two pins that work with I2C. So if you connected your sensors a different way, which I assume means you used different pins, then the sensor (which I assume is I2C) won't work with standard I2C scripts. Try connecting the sensor to the proper I2C pins (SDA and SCL).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to switch to GPIO2 and GPIO3, which are the only two I2C on raspberry pi 2, but still get nothing. I'm using DHT11 sensor.

Comment: @TracyYang Aha! DHT11 does _not_ use I2C. Could you share your wiring and setup?

Comment: Will do so when I get a chance. Does BME280 have I2C? If DHT11 does not use I2C, is there other way I can send data to Azure?

Comment: @TracyYang yes, it doesn't matter what protocol (like I2c) the sensor uses, you just need to be able to get data from the sensor. I'm not familiar with the `index.js` script you are using, though, but probably you'll need to modify it in order to send different sensor data. Do you understand node.js?

Comment: Not really. I just followed the instructions in the link above. Do you want me to post the index.js?

Comment: No. You don't need to. (I can access it from the link above.) But that index.js script I believe was programmed for the BME280 so either you'll have to get a BME280 or else you'll have to program or look for a different script. If you know python, you could try looking up how to access Azure from python and then write your own script. @TracyYang

Comment: yeah, I figured it that out. I can now read real time data into Azure IoT hub. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TracyYang good!